# Azure AD as WSO2 v4.0 keymanager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm planning to use Azure AD as a 3rd party key manager in WSO2 API manager version 4.0

It looks like there are only some predefined set as keymanagers. I couldn't find Azure AD in the list.

Is there any way that i can configure Azure AD as a keymanager?

Appreciate any insights on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write a custom key manager connector[1] for this purpose.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-custom-connector/#configure-a-custom-key-manager

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check it.